# I would like to get all transactions given an address

Tags: python, api, blockchain, solana

Given a Solana wallet address I would like to verify every single transaction ever confirmed to check other information, such as the receiver (or sender) and the amount sent (or received). So, as usual, I searched for some APIs. I found the following:

1. [Solana py](https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/index.html)
2. [PySolana](https://pypi.org/project/pysolana/)

After that, I went to look which methods they offer. The one that seems to be close to what I wish is solana_client.get_confirmed_signature_for_address2 (available in 1), however my results do not match what its documentation shows. Here it is:

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
solana_client = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")

solana_client.get_signatures_for_address("2AQdpHJ2JpcEgPiATUXjQxA8QmafFegfQwSLWSprPicm", limit=1)
```

I get this:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'result': [], 'id': 1}
```

However, I should get its last signature, which seems to be this:

4SNQ4h1vL9GkmSnojQsf8SZyFvQsaq62RCgops2UXFYag1Jc4MoWrjTg2ELwMqM1tQbn9qUcNc4tqX19EGHBqC5u

Anyways, we can use SolanaBeach and [check](https://solanabeach.io/address/2AQdpHJ2JpcEgPiATUXjQxA8QmafFegfQwSLWSprPicm). Further, if we code as the documentation explains:

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
solana_client = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")

solana_client.get_signatures_for_address("Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111", limit=1)
```

I get this:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'result': [{'blockTime': 1637328065, 'confirmationStatus': 'finalized', 'err': {'InstructionError': [0, {'Custom': 0}]}, 'memo': None, 'signature': '5yaeqDRCHWCGQMqNWhq3g6zqw63MBkri9i86hjK954YFFvnG2VCQJfszXsozDVUJbePagJieAzwsSY5H7Xd1jJhC', 'slot': 95301596}], 'id': 1}
```

Weird thing is "Vote111...11" seems not to be an address. Nevertheless, I get expected results, that is a signature, even though such signature can't be found by Solana Explorer...

Please, tell me what to fix. I have no idea what to do. I even tried to check if all Solana Explorers have their own API, but they do not. Probably because Solana already shares it, right?

**EDIT**

Well, it seems I need to enter the "account address as base-58 encoded string", thus the address becomes: HLiBGYYxaQqQx8UTPHEahqcd7aZjkDgN3bihc3hYM3SDUBGU9LFrQSnx9eje.

I also did that and I get:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'error': {'code': -32602, 'message': 'Invalid param: WrongSize'}, 'id': 1}
```

Comment: you could add some real addresses which we could use to test code and its modifications.

Comment: Sure @furas, I'll edit. However, the "address" Vote11111...11 is an example shown in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is not `module` nor `function` but `endpoint`.

In [Solana Doc](https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints) I found `endpoint` for `mainnet`:

```
https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

https://solana-api.projectserum.com
```

and it gives all values.

---

On [other page](https://docs.solana.com/clusters) you can see that

- `devnet` is only `playground` for tests and `tokens are not real`
- `testnet` is only for `stress test` and `tokens are not real`

```
#Devnet#

- Devnet serves as a playground for anyone who wants to take Solana for a test drive, as a user, token holder, app developer, or validator.
- Application developers should target Devnet.
- Potential validators should first target Devnet.
- Key differences between Devnet and Mainnet Beta:
    - Devnet tokens are not real
    - Devnet includes a token faucet for airdrops for application testing
    - Devnet may be subject to ledger resets
    - Devnet typically runs a newer software version than Mainnet Beta

#Testnet#

-Testnet is where we stress test recent release features on a live cluster, particularly focused on network performance, stability and validator behavior.
- Testnet tokens are not real
- Testnet may be subject to ledger resets.
- Testnet includes a token faucet for airdrops for application testing
- Testnet typically runs a newer software release than both Devnet and Mainnet Beta
```

---

Minimal working example for tests:

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client

all_addresses = [
    '2AQdpHJ2JpcEgPiATUXjQxA8QmafFegfQwSLWSprPicm',
    'Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111',
    'fake address',
]

#endpoint = 'https://api.devnet.solana.com'    # probably for `developing`
#endpoint = 'https://api.testnet.solana.com'   # probably for `testing`
endpoint = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'
#endpoint = 'https://solana-api.projectserum.com'

solana_client = Client(endpoint)

for address in all_addresses:
    print('address:', address)
    
    #result = solana_client.get_confirmed_signature_for_address2(address, limit=1)
    result = solana_client.get_signatures_for_address(address)#, before='89Tv9s2uMGaoxB8ZF1LV9nGa72GQ9RbkeyCDvfPviWesZ6ajZBFeHsTPfgwjGEnH7mpZa7jQBXAqjAfMrPirHt2')
    
    if 'result' in result:
        print('len:', len(result['result']))

        # I use `[:5]` to display only first 5 values
        for number, item in enumerate(result['result'][:5], 1):
            print(number, 'signature:', item['signature'])

        # check if there is `4SNQ4h1vL9GkmSnojQsf8SZyFvQsaq62RCgops2UXFYag1Jc4MoWrjTg2ELwMqM1tQbn9qUcNc4tqX19EGHBqC5u`
        for number, item in enumerate(result['result'], 1):
            if item['signature'].startswith('4SN'):
                print('found at', number, '>>>', item['signature'])

    else:
        # error message 
        print(result)

    print('---')

    #solana_client.get_account_info(address)
```

Result:

```
address: 2AQdpHJ2JpcEgPiATUXjQxA8QmafFegfQwSLWSprPicm
len: 1000
1 signature: 89Tv9s2uMGaoxB8ZF1LV9nGa72GQ9RbkeyCDvfPviWesZ6ajZBFeHsTPfgwjGEnH7mpZa7jQBXAqjAfMrPirHt2
2 signature: 3Ku2rDnAVo5Mj3r9CVSGHJjvn4H9rxzDvc5Cg5uyeCC9oa6p7enAG88pSfRfxcqhBh2JiWSo7ZFEAD3mP8teS1Yg
3 signature: 3wiYCmfXb9n6pT3mgBag7jx6jBjeKZowkYmeakMibw4GtERFyyitrmmoPU6t28HpJJgWkArymWEGWQj8eiojswoD
4 signature: 5vjV1wKU3ZEgyzqXCKrJcJx5jGC8LPqRiJBwhPcu62HQU64mkrvkK8LKYaTzX4x4p26UXSufWM57zKSxRrMgjWn3
5 signature: 3aLk4xZPcWRogtvsFe8geYC177PK8s47mgqUErteRc9NJ4EF2iHi3GPsaj5guTwyiabhwivFhrrEk4YQgiE2hZs8
found at 970 >>> 4SNQ4h1vL9GkmSnojQsf8SZyFvQsaq62RCgops2UXFYag1Jc4MoWrjTg2ELwMqM1tQbn9qUcNc4tqX19EGHBqC5u
---
address: Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111
len: 1000
1 signature: 67RRbUWGCrwmJ3hhLL7aB2K8gc6MewxwgAdfG7FeXQBaSstacqvuo9QUPZ6nhqXjJwYpKHihNJwFfcaAZHuyFmMc
2 signature: 67PsyRRw8bXgtsB49htxcW2FE9cyyBrocUKacnrxJpqaBpFT6QDLrCkyovWnM8XyGKxTv3kqzmW72SH7gj3N8YJr
3 signature: 675FWqrAjE5Bt6rf3KD2H2PCKUmEtrcD8BRRypdS7m2V22zXhrGn3SktP6JYW4ws6xEqDj52MZMH8RwNjoqgW4mt
4 signature: 671K7N9FwaMAyBC4MEYbYb1ACYAendBbRMqKPvr3h63dt5ybAPHyppjHwxq1yPDjqaRUwCBVU9o5dVqgsdVabint
5 signature: 666jBXXLwmB5tuvufhNn8Q7A3eCzGo6CBFD5BYJkuGfBf1bRoAGz4DeEpUAKsUrRk4NdRBhYkwfrhyZjgFmo3Dp2
---
address: fake address
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'error': {'code': -32602, 'message': 'Invalid param: Invalid'}, 'id': 3}
---
```

---

**BTW:**

Because it gets only 1000 values you may not see `4SNQ...` which is at position ~1200 at this moment, but if you use `before=`

```
get_signatures_for_address(address, before='89Tv9s2uMGaoxB8ZF1LV9nGa72GQ9RbkeyCDvfPviWesZ6ajZBFeHsTPfgwjGEnH7mpZa7jQBXAqjAfMrPirHt2')
```

then it should be at position ~970

---

**BTW:**

On [Solana Explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/) you have big button to change `Mainnet` to `Devnet` and when you use `Devnet` then
[2AQdpHJ2JpcEgPiATUXjQxA8QmafFegfQwSLWSprPicm](https://explorer.solana.com/address/2AQdpHJ2JpcEgPiATUXjQxA8QmafFegfQwSLWSprPicm?cluster=devnet) also gives 0 items.

The same on [Solana Beach](https://solanabeach.io/validators). There is also big button to change `Mainnet` to `Devnet` and when you use `Devnet` then
[2AQdpHJ2JpcEgPiATUXjQxA8QmafFegfQwSLWSprPicm](https://solanabeach.io/address/2AQdpHJ2JpcEgPiATUXjQxA8QmafFegfQwSLWSprPicm?cluster=devnet) gives 0 items.

Comment: Mr. furas, thank you so much! I was not aware of the diferences between the endpoints! Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you very much! so any idea what to do if there are over 1000 transactions? should I just use `before=` and equate it to the 1000th transaction?

Comment: @NazimKerimbekov you could use `before=` with `1000th transaction`

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented the function to get all the transactions of a given address on javaScript this might help you out.

```
    async getTransactionsOfUser(address, options, connection) {
    console.log({ address, options });
    try {
      const publicKey = new PublicKey(address);
      const transSignatures =
        await connection.getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2(publicKey, options);
      console.log({ transSignatures });
      const transactions = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < transSignatures.length; i++) {
        const signature = transSignatures[i].signature;
        const confirmedTransaction = await connection.getConfirmedTransaction(
          signature,
        );
        if (confirmedTransaction) {
          const { meta } = confirmedTransaction;
          if (meta) {
            const oldBalance = meta.preBalances;
            const newBalance = meta.postBalances;
            const amount = oldBalance[0] - newBalance[0];
            const transWithSignature = {
              signature,
              ...confirmedTransaction,
              fees: meta?.fee,
              amount,
            };
            transactions.push(transWithSignature);
          }
        }
      }
      return transactions;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, Abdul, thanks for your answer. I wish it could help me out, but I know nothing of JavaScript. Anyways, thank you, this may help other people!

Comment: Hi @Abdul Qadir Thanks for this. But this method is not giving all transactions. It's giving only 4-5 transactions

Answer (score 2):

funny I was working on this exact same issue this morning.. and just like furas pointed out, it's the endpoint, need to use the mainnet endpoint:

```
https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
```

And I found it's bit confusing even though the doc says you need to input base-58 address, I tried same as you did it gives me the same error, turns out I just need to copy paste my address directly

Comment: Yeah! That's also confusing. We don't even need to do that